# What is the percentage for a tag in your careers profile?

Tags: support, jobs

There is a percentage displayed in the Careers profile.
[image]

Does anybody know what the basis of this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basis is your total tag score (which consists of both question and answers, non CW) as can be seen in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884521/bboymaanu):

> [image]

Which is then compared against the scores of all other users who took part in this tag.

As posted in the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224250/152859) you can see the top 20 users of the tag and to get full list you can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). (will write something up if I'll have time :))

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian yeah, it's very old query guess the database schema was changed since then.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard jQuery should be the first if the percentage considering with both question and answer :)

Answer (score 3):

It means that you're in the top 20% of all users in the google-maps-api-3 tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:884521+[google-maps-api-3]

here's a better link

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-3/topusers

Comment: you mean on the basis of questions or answer or both ?